# Is there a way to align the middle of the circle to the top of the grey rectangles?

Tags: html, css

I'd like the circles to be vertically aligned so that the middle of the circle is in line with the top of the div box.

Is there a way to make it the "most responsive" if that makes sense.

```
CSS: 
    #feature .feature-thumb {
      background-color: #eaeaea;
      position: relative;
      padding: 40px;
      margin-top: 32px;
    }

    #feature .feature-icon {
      background-color: #64beeb;
      width: 85px;
      height: 85px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 0;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -ms-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: table;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    #feature .feature-icon:hover {
      background-color: #eaeaea;
    }

    #feature .feature-icon span {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #feature .feature-icon .fa {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/minacosentino/pen/YxLLQw?editors=1100)

Comment: Repsonsive in relation to what? What do you expect to change size: the text/the icon/both?

Comment: so if they were to access this site on a mobile device, i don't want the circle to move around, i'd like the middle of the circle to stay vertically aligned to the top of the box (sorry i'm relatively new with all of this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#feature .feature-icon {
  background-color: #64beeb;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  top: 0; /* Changed here */
  left: 50%; /* Changed here */
  position: absolute; /* Changed here */
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Changed here */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Changed here */
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Changed here */
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Changed here */
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Changed here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to adjust that icon circle only small screens you can use media query **@media** for that and then you can style which you want.
And If you want this for all screen you can use this style as well outside of media query in you **icon** class style which you are already using.
Here is the solved example of your project

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px){
   #feature .feature-icon {
      top:-70px;
   }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sikandar_ali_akram/pen/QMxZvJ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `feature_icon` with the following style:

```
position: absolute;
margin-top: -42.5px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -42.5px;
```

And you need to set the padding on `#feature .feature-thumb`

```
padding:0px 40px 40px 40px;
```

This will get you started .. You'll still have to push your text down with either padding or margin because it will be alinged to the top of the gray box with this `CSS` change.